# How can I crop a portion from an image specified by 4 corner points in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to crop only the portion closed by red lines in this image:-

[image]

I have the four corner points `(x1,y1)` ,  `(x2,y2)` , `(x3,y3)` , `(x4,y4)`. I tried `imcrop` but that's for rectangular crop. Output image needs to be RGB.

Comment: What shape do you expect the resulting image (matrix) to be?

Comment: Shape of the resulting image will be the same as the red box drawn

Comment: Unfortunately, images and matrices are rectangular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used google search to find your [original image file](http://www.hobbykweker.nl/images/Lori%20van%20de%20Blauwe%20Bergen.jpg):-

[image: original file]

Now, if I understand your question correctly, this is what you're looking for:

```
I=imread('nYNKB.jpg');
Isize = size(I);

mask = poly2mask([43 214 227 123],[131 22 112 198],Isize(1,1),Isize(1,2));
% where [x1,x2,x3,x4] = [43 214 227 123] & [y1,y2,y3,y4] = [131 22 112 198]

I_masked = bsxfun(@times,I,cast(mask,class(I)));

subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(I);
title('Original Image')

subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(I_masked)
title('Masked Image')
```

**Output:-**
[image: output]

---

### **Edit:-**

If you do not want the black background, the closest you can go is with this:

```
figure(2)
mask = bsxfun(@eq,I_masked,reshape([0 0 0],1,1,3));
image(I_masked,'alphadata',1-double(all(mask,3)));
axis off
title('Masked Image')
```

**Output:-**

[image: output1]

---

---

**Alternate Solution (if output does not have to be RGB) :-**

```
I = rgb2gray(imread('nYNKB.jpg'));
imshow(I);
h = imfreehand; 
M = ~h.createMask();
I(M) = 0;
imshow(I);
```

[image: gif_output]

Comment: Thanks ! but is there any way to display only the portion bounded by the four corner points. What I mean is, in your code, it takes the whole image and then it do the masking to give the final output. But how to display only the cropped portion of the original image ?

Comment: @Rifat ! what I understand from your above comment is that you want to have a matrix that doesn't have elements at some of its indexes. This is not mathematically possible!

Comment: @Rifat As I said in my comments above, images are rectangular. You can crop to the bounding rectangle of the polygon to get a smaller area of the original image, but it's always going to be rectangular.

Comment: @Rifat See the latest edit !! You may find it more useful!!